# ng-checked='true' not working

Tags: angularjs, html, radio-button, angularjs-ng-checked

Template - 1

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <label><input type="radio" ng-checked="true" /> One</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label ng-click="ctrl.goToTwo()"><input type="radio" /> Two</label>
  </li>
<ul>
```

Template - 2

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <label ng-click="ctrl.goToOne()"><input type="radio" /> One</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label><input type="radio" ng-checked="true" /> Two</label>
  </li>
<ul>
```

In above html, I am just redirecting user to template 1 to template 2 with the help of radio buttons.

**Question**
I have clearly mentioned `ng-checked=true` in one the radio button in both templates. But i dont know why they both are coming unchecked while loading.

Please let me know if I am missing something and or need to do something else.

note: I have tried playing with `ng-model='one'` and `vm.type='one'` but its not working.

Comment: please use value for radio tag..Use the model and pre declare model value in controller. refer this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/ZQDts/3/

Comment: @Sathish : I have already tried it, but i dont know whats going wrong.

Comment: Create a plunker reproducing issue.. though it looks trivial and caused because of some tiny mistake. check for that first maybe

Comment: I think you code has problem, please share your full source.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add a "value" to the "radio" input

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="myRadio" value="1" />
```

later in your code

```
$scope.myRadio = "1" // check radio
$scope.myRadio = "0" // radio not checked
```

Demo:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QvKNOQ

Comment: @Era well my code example is working, please provide a demo of your code.

Answer (score 1):

ng-checked is used to evaluate an **expression**:

> ## [`ngChecked`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)
>
> Sets the `checked` attribute on the element, if the expression inside
> `ngChecked` is truthy.

So using `ng-checked="true"` will search for a `$scope.true` variable, which is obviously not what you are looking for.

---

If you are using `ng-model` on your inputs, you can default set the `ng-model` value:

```
<div ng-init="ctrlNumber = 1">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="ctrlNumber" value="1"/>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="ctrlNumber" value=2"/>
</div>
```

When you will submit your form, check for the `ctrlNumber` value: if `2`, call your `ctrl.goToTwo()` function.

<sub>*Note you can also set this value in your controller, without `ng-init`.*</sub>